# ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION: Async function error using Typescript and Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asynchronous, jestjs

I have the following code:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchInfo = async () => {
    const config = await fetchAnimal(animalIdFromSite);
    if (config) {
      setAnimal(config.animal);
    }
  };

  fetchInfo();
}, [animalIdFromSite]);

const fetchAnimal = async (animalId: string): Promise<Configuration | null> => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      `${process.env.animalSite}/animal/${animalId}`
    );
    return response.data as Configuration;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Unable to get configuration: ${error}`);
    return null;
  }
};
```

I get the following error:

```
[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either
 by throwing inside of an async function without a 
catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was 
not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with 
the reason "[object Object]".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
```

My test looks like this:

```
test("renders content area with display id", () => {
  render(
    <MemoryRouter initialEntries={["/id/23"]}>
      <App />
    </MemoryRouter>
  );

  expect(screen.getByRole("content")).toHaveClass("content-area");
});
```

If i remove the test, my code passes. I'm confused because I've already set up the catches in the function

Comment: Try adding `fetchInfo().catch(console.error)`. The error may be caused by a typo